# Conditional of a Hyperexponential Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For the exponential distribution, we know that:
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X > t + s \mid X > s\} = \mathbb{P}\{X > t\},
$$
i.e. if we condition the exponential distribution it is again an exponential distribution.

For a hyperexponential distribution we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X > t + s \mid X > s\} > \mathbb{P}\{X > t\},
$$
but I was wondering what we can say about the conditional distribution $(X \mid X > s)$, is it again Hyperexponential? If so: what parameters does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=2$, the cdf of $Y$, the random variable of hyperexponential [distribution with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,p,1-p$ is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperexponential_distribution)

$$P(Y<y)=(1-e^{-\lambda_1y})p+(1-e^{-\lambda_2y})(1-p). \tag 1$$

Let's compute the conditional cdf, that is the conditional probability $$P(Y<y \ \mid Y>s)=\frac{P(Y<y\ \cap\ Y>s) }{P(Y>s)}$$
where (and in what follows) it is assumed that $s\leq y$. If $s>y$ then the probability in question is $0$.

First, $$P(Y<y\ \cap\ Y>s)=$$$$=P(Y<y\ \cap\ Y>s\ \mid Y=X_1)p+P(Y<y\ \cap\ Y>s\ \mid Y=X_2)(1-p)=$$$$=P(X_1<y\ \cap\ X_1>s)p+P(X_1<y\ \cap\ X_2>s)(1-p)=$$
$$=(e^{-\lambda_1y}-e^{-\lambda_1s})p+(e^{-\lambda_2y}-e^{-\lambda_2s})(1-p).$$

Second,

$$P(Y>s)=e^{-\lambda_1s}p+e^{-\lambda_2s}(1-p).$$

So,

$$P(Y<y\ \mid \ Y>s)=\begin{cases}\frac{(e^{-\lambda_1y}-e^{-\lambda_1s})p+(e^{-\lambda_2y}-e^{-\lambda_2s})(1-p)}{e^{-\lambda_1s}p+e^{-\lambda_2s}(1-p)}&\text{ if } s\leq y\\
0&\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}\\
$$

This is not of the form of $(1)$.

Comment: A bit of a let down but thanks :)!

Comment: I did not mean that. : )